# testcafe is opening a browser and defaulting to /browser/connect/.... and unable to execute the test

Tags: node.js, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have been trying to run testcafe using nodejs but the browser is unable to proceed and execute the script. It is showing this error in the console:
Unable to establish one or more of the specified browser connections. This can be caused by network issues or remote device failure.

I only have a simple test case.

```
fixture`Home page`
  .page`http://www.google.com`;  // specify the start page

test("The heading should be...", async t => {
  const title = Selector('h1');
  await t.expect('t').eql('t')
});
```

Can anyone help, please?

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It might be possible that you need to add the option `--hostname localhost` and/or the [--proxy](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#--proxy-host) option to the TestCafe command-line.

Comment: Assuming that works, why is it necessary?